# How do I open file using text editor(ATOM)?

Tags: github, terminal, atom-editor

I wanted to open file using Atom from Mac Terminal. But I get an error msg -bash: atom: command not found.

Ive created a depository on GitHub, and I am managed to clone my git hub repository in my terminal and create a file, now I need to use a text editor (ATOM) to create a web page. Where do I go from here? I want to link my terminal, ATOM and GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't have atom installed on your system.

to install it press the download button from the https://atom.io. Once you have that file, you can click on it to extract the application and then drag the new Atom application into your "Applications" folder.

full guide [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-mac)